# linegraph within scatterplot with D3 v3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, scatter-plot, linegraph

i am working on a project where i am trying to use this tutorial http://bl.ocks.org/dukevis/6768900. Now i want to incorporate a stock chart within the scatterplot. Through this I can show historic events on the world map and indicate their position on the stocks using the scatterpoints in the left chart. The problem now is that I am trying to use a Unix Timestamp in order to plot the linegraph. However (I believe) the line chart does not handle the timestamp. Spend al day on this and literally getting nowhere. The code I use to create the line is:

```
    var createdScale = d3.time.scale()
      .domain([minCreated, maxCreated])
      .range([cx, width])

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, maxScore])
      .range([height, cx])

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d,i) { return createdScale(d.created); })
      .y(function(d,i) { return yScale(d.score); });

    // 9. Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator 
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line 
        .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling 
        .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator
```

This results into the following error:
**Error:  attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".**.

Data is in the following json:

```
{
"AdjClose":59.689999,
"Close":59.689999,
"Date":-315619200,
"High":60.389999,
"Low":59.689999,
"Open":59.91,
"Volume":14740000,
"average":60.039999,
"color":"#cc3399",
"country":"usa",
"created":-315619200,
"id":"usa0","num_comments":1,
"score":0.0178304676,
"created_us":-315619200},
{
"AdjClose":59.689999,
"Close":59.689999,
"Date":-315619200,
"High":60.389999,
"Low":59.689999,
"Open":59.91,
"Volume":14740000,
"average":60.039999,
"color":"#cc3399",
"country":"usa",
"created":-315615600,
"id":"usa0",
"num_comments":1,
"score":0.0178304676,
"created_us":-315615600}
```

I included a link to my github for the project code here: https://github.com/jonasschui/visualisation

As people might already have guessed, I have only very little experience with D3 :)
All credits and thanks to the tutorials from dukevis (http://bl.ocks.org/dukevis/6768900). Check him out for some more cool stuff. Anyone that is willing to help, Thank you!

Comment: The code linked to on github fails with `TypeError: world is undefined`. Could you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Very sorry about that. Missed to upload the country geojson. Included it now and tested the repo. Now it produced the same output I have at home. Once again sorry for the miss.P.S. the graph takes about 15 secs to load :)

Comment: `svg.line().x` in scatterplot.js is not causing the problem: `.x(function(d,i) { console.log(d.created, createdScale(d.created)); return createdScale(d.created); })` shows that there is no `NaN` generated in there.

Comment: Suggestion: aggregate the dataset: there certainly are ways to provide valuable insights without loading 24 Mb of data and representing 75k+ individual data points.

Comment: Haha, no indeed it's not. That's why i am trying to load it in as a line chart so I can reduce the amount of datapoint. This representation was mearly there to see if the stock trend was making any sense :)